# File does not exist error when I run hello.go program

Tags: windows, go

I am following go documentation and try to run hello.go.
I am on Windows 7 and install go 1.1.2 using msi installer.
I have file "C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386\8g.exe" (see dir output below), but when I do 'go.exe run hello.go', I get the file does not exist error.

Please help. Thank you.

```
C:\>go.exe run hello.go
go build command-line-arguments: exec: "C:\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_386\\8g.exe":
 file does not exist

C:\>go.exe version
go version go1.1.2 windows/386

C:\>go.exe run hello.go
go build command-line-arguments: exec: "C:\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_386\\8g.exe":
 file does not exist

C:\>dir C:\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_386\\8g.exe
The specified path is invalid.

C:\>dir C:\Go\pkg\tool\\windows_386\\8g.exe
 Volume in drive C is Local Disk
 Volume Serial Number is C07E-54F5

 Directory of C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386

08/13/2013  07:04 AM         1,831,416 8g.exe
               1 File(s)      1,831,416 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  11,407,892,480 bytes free
```

Comment: For me the issue was that I'd set GOOS to linux while trying to run on Windows.

Comment: Restarting command prompt(CMD) worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

From [issue 6224](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6224), this error happens if you had the environment variable `PATHEXT` set to only one extension, before running `go.exe`.

1. `set PATHEXT=.BAT`
2. `go run hello.go`

> What is the expected output?
>   no errors and hello world program runs
>
> What do you see instead?

```
go build command-line-arguments: 
exec: "c:\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_386\\8g.exe": file does not exist
```

8g
Windows 7 64bit
go version go1.1.2 windows/386

---

On my computer (W7 64 bits), I have:

```
set pa
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

and everything runs just fine.

> `LookPath` is called with "`c:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386\8g.exe`" and the fact that `PATHEXT` is being set in an evil way let's say, make `LookPath` fails

Comment: I.e. `PATHEXT` should et least include `.EXE`.

Answer (score 1):

For windows users :

If using vscode type this on terminal

> `$env:GOOS="windows"`

else type this in windows powershell